# Full screen iAd on older SDKs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, I don't have any devices to test this on, so I'm hoping one of you has the answer.
I'm just downloading XCode 4 and I want to use the new full screen iAds, but I don't want to force my users to download iOS 4.3. Do you know if my app would still work on older versions of iOS if I simply set the deployment target to 4.0 and the base SDK stays at 4.3?

Thank you

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that greystripe does this, but it doesn't pay as well as I'd thought (maybe $0.08 per click, and only 2% CTR with lower impressions). In the end: not worth it.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 1):

take a look here, it's explained all what you ara asking:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Comment: it's not about full-screen iAds introduced in iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know exactly but I think your users need iOS 4.3 for full-screen iAds. I make this conclusion on fact apple sample app iAdInterstitialSuite - states Runtime Requirements: 
iOS 4.3 or later. And in ADInterstitialAd class references says Availability:
Available in iOS 4.3 and later.

and btw dont forget - "Full-Screen Advertisements are Only Available on iPad

To test whether full-screen advertisements are available, retrieve the value of the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM macro; if the value returned from this macro is UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad, you may use full-screen advertisements."